# Angular state management - Store or Stateful services?

Tags: angular, ngrx-store, ngxs

We currently have a medium-large Angular 6 (prod bundle = 5MB) application with ngrx/store as state management implemented.

We choose ngrx/store because at the time (NG2) everybody used it and it seemed like a good idea to store state and access state this way.
In other words: the wrong reasons.

It feels more and more like a layer of indirection which isn't required, since services can hold state and return streams to access parts of the application state with much less boilerplate (even with NGXS).

**Question**

*From an architectural point of view, why would we choose ngrx/store or NGXS over plain stateful services?*

Please only real-world arguments, no theoretical or purist arguments.

If handled properly a few plain @Injectable services with a few streams result in clean code, no boilerplate code, and full responsibility of state. Even immutability can easily be handled ourselves.

(Yes I know there are some technical advantages if you get them working properly like restoring state in HMR and inspecting state, but we never got that consistently and properly working )

Comment: I am struggling with the same question here.

Comment: All of the solutions imply using anaemic data model i.e a plain object with no behaviour. This way you cannot force some validation on it or in any other way ensure that the model is actually in a consistent state. Also, I dislike having a dependency to Store for selecting and dispatching instead of just a state object I am really working with... NGXS makes it much more in line with Angular compared to NGRX, but it is still kind of indirect in these aspects.

Comment: This blog post covers all the information you need and is also very informative in terms of understanding application state management in general. Give it a read: [Angular Application State Management: You Do (Not) Need External Data Stores](https://codeeve.com/2020/02/28/angular-application-state-management-you-do-not-need-external-data-stores-like-ngrx-redux-and-other/)

Answer (score 4):

There are several good reasons to use NgRX:

1) It prevents you from needing lots of little services all over, which are much harder to manage and track than the single NgRx store.

2) The store provides a client-side cache so you don't need to re-get the data from the server every time ... only when you need to. And yes, you can do that in your own service as well, just with more code.

3) Using selectors, any component can be easily notified of any change to a specific piece of data, making notifications across the system easy ... even when changing to multiple pages. Again, you can do this in your own service using Subject/BehaviorSubject, but why reinvent the wheel.

4) There is a standard pattern and flow that can be generated using the Angular CLI, making it easier to ensure that all of the code of your application remains consistent.

5) You can use the debugging tools to easily see what's going on. At my last several talks many devs wanted to move to NgRX *just* for this feature. :-) You said you had trouble getting that to work properly?

[image]

Comment: The DevTools work alright, but not with HMR unfortunately. It's probably something we're doing wrong. Sometimes the store just isn't restored properly.

And I can imagine that putting our state in one StateService with a properly typed state object and implementing results in a very small piece of code, without all the boilerplate of reducers, actions, effects etc which we now have.

I just is getting harder to justify and explain to new developers why we do it.

Comment: Consider posting to the github issues for NgRX. The devs on the team are very helpful!

Comment: And I'll probably be crucified for saying this ... but for new developers I have a course: "Angular NgRX: Getting Started" that may help.

Comment: No, you won't be crucified :) And I have plenty material on HOW to implement and use NgRX/store, but not the exact WHY, which is my question all about.

Comment: The course has a whole section on the "why" as well. (That's where the above info came from.) Is that "why" enough or are you looking for something more? (I'll add more above ...)

Comment: Thanks for your time. I currenly have no active Pluralsight account so I can't watch it. I still am not convinced we still need NgRx/store if there is no complex shared state with multiple sources which modify state. I will keep looking for answers.

Comment: Click the "Start a 10 day free trial" button. I recently did a project using BehaviorSubject everywhere and was so proud of myself for implementing all of its features. Then I learned NgRx and was bummed how much time I had wasted trying to implement all that NgRx does. But if you truly see no need ... then take it out. :-) ---------- But one last question ... what type of answer would convince you otherwise? What is it that you are looking for?